# Finding the number of characters separating two substrings in a string

Tags: r

I have a data frame, `df`, that looks like:

```
string            substring        
abcxxxxxZxxabc    abc               
defxdefxZxdefx    def
```

I would like a distance column:

```
string            substring   distances
abcxxxxxZxxabc    abc         5, 2
defxdefxZxdefx    def         5, 1, 1
```

What I essentially want to do is find the "distances" (number of chars in between) between the strings in `df$substring` and "Z" in `df$string`.

The order of the distances does not matter and if important, everything in `df$string` is the same length, with "Z" always in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
transform(
  df,
  distance =
    mapply(
      function(x, y) {
        u <- gregexpr(y, x)[[1]] - gregexpr("Z", x)[[1]]
        toString(ifelse(u < 0, -(u + nchar(y)), u - 1))
      },
      string,
      substring,
      USE.NAMES = FALSE
    )
)
```

which gives

```
          string substring distance
1 abcxxxxxZxxabc       abc     5, 2
2 defxdefxZxdefx       def  5, 1, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
 mutate(new = map2(str_extract_all(string,
     sprintf('(?<=%s).*(?=Z)|(?<=Z).*(?=%s)', substring, substring)),
      substring, ~{
        n <- nchar(.x)
        i1 <- str_detect(.x, .y)
        c(n, nchar(str_remove(.x[i1], str_c(".*", .y))))
        
       }))
```

Comment: It seems like this finds the "distance" of only the first match on the left of the Z and only one match on the right of Z. For instance, changing the string in the second row to `defxdefxZxxdefx` should return `5, 1, 2`, but instead it returns `5, 2`. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @beginnerRuser19 For that stirng, the number of characters between the 'def' and 'Z' is 5 and Z and def is 2 and the last case `defx` doesn't have any 'Z' at the end

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but `defx` does have a 'Z' at the end. The substring is `defxZ`, which should give a "distance" of 1. Is there any way to account for this?

Comment: @beginnerRuser19 your string is `defxdefxZxdefx` where is `Z` at the end

Comment: @beginnerRuser19 with the current code i get `5, 1` for the sceond

Comment: Sorry I should have made it more clear but in the first comment I changed the string slightly to `defxdefxZxxdefx`. Note that now there are two `x` after the `Z`. With this new string, I only get `5, 2` with the current code, when it should be `5, 1, 2`.

Comment: @beginnerRuser19 in the new string, `defxdefxZ` this gives 5 and the next match is `Zxxdef` which is 2

Comment: In the string `defxdefxZ` there are two `def` substrings with "distances" of 5 and 1. Is there a way to account for both?

Comment: @beginnerRuser19 in the current code with extract_all, it matches only once and doesn't do a recursive match again